# Github, how to find out my username?

Tags: git, github

I want to start using git

This is my github repo

https://github.com/MilenkoM

Is my username
MilenkoM?

```
git config --global user.name
```

shows nothing because I have not used git on UBuntu,I have just forked repos from other people

Can I see this from the command line on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to find user GitHub username using the Git CLI. You can find your full name and email address, however.

```
git config user.name
git config user.email
```

An important distinction to make is that Git is not the same as GitHub. GitHub can sort of be considered as a large-scale web-based Git repository hosting service. Git, however, is a version control system written by the creator of Linux, Linus Torvalds.

Your username is indeed 'MilenkoM' and your full name is 'Milenko'. Your email address will probably be shown as 'milenko.markovic@gmail.com'.

Comment: That is true,I understand now.I can config user.name on my comp but I am afraid that it could create problems when I try to commit.